# Influxdb - doing math with field by different tags

Tags: influxdb, influxql

| time | value(fileld) | type(tag) | object(tag) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | a | X |
| 1 | 7 | b | X |
| 2 | 3 | a | X |
| 2 | 2 | b | X |

My measurement looks like this. I want to create SELECT that returns me difference of values with tag "a" and values with tag "b" (they have the same time) and GROUP it by "object" (there is several of them). Basicly a-b operation for all values.

The result should look like this:

| time | value(fileld) | type(tag) | object(tag) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -2 | - | X |
| 2 | 1 | - | X |

I have tried this but it didnt work.

```
SELECT "value_a" - "value_b" as dif
FROM
    (SELECT "value" as "value_a" FROM "table" WHERE "type" = a') GROUP BY „object“),
    (SELECT "value" as "value_b" FROM "table" WHERE "type" = 'b') GROUP BY „object“)
GROUP BY "OBJ_2"
```

It only works for: mean("value_a") - mean("value_b") but that is not what i am looking.
I want to use the result in Grafana so if there is a way to do it there via some Grafana math operations its also fine.

Thanks for any help!